# Cloud Firestore change field name

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

my database like;

[image]

I want, when announcement0 field is deleted, announcement1 field name to change announcement0. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to rename fields in Firestore, let alone to have that happen automatically.

It sounds like you have multiple announcements in your document however. In that case, you could consider storing all announcements in a single array field `announcements`. In an array field, when you remove the first item (at index 0) all other items after that shift down in the array to take its place, which seems to be precisely what you want.

Comment: Does `arrayRemove` work with arrays of objects? (or do you need to overwrite the entire array?)

Comment: yes, the array thing is so sensible for my situation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename fields in a document. You'll have to delete and recreate it.
Now I'm assuming the number just defines the order of document. If that's the case you can use this workaround, instead of looking for 'announcement0' on client side, you can just store a number field in the document such as 0 in announcement0 and so on. So to get announcement1 when announcement0 is deleted you can uses this query:

```
const firstAnnouncement = await dbRef.orderBy('number').limit(1).get()
```

This will get the announcement with least number (highest rank). You can change the limit as per your needs.

But if renaming fields is needed then you'll have to delete and recreate all trailing announcements.